# How to generate a URL to load specific content on page

Tags: javascript, url

I need to be able to provide a URL that when clicked points to this page:
https://my.blood.co.uk/SessionFinder
but where instead of loading a blank search form, a specific set of search results are given (i.e with a specific `location`, `datefrom` and `dateto` value given).

Basically I need to be able to provide a url of the format `https://my.blood.co.uk/SessionFinder?a=location...`. Is this possible? How would I go about identifying the correct parameters?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have control over the code at https://my.blood.co.uk/SessionFinder?

Comment: No, I don't... I just need to be able to direct people to the search results for a specific date range and location

Answer (score 0):

It depends if the page accepts GET requests instead of POST. The form on that page has POST as the `action` parameter, so it's not sure. You can always try compiling the form, so you can check which parameters are sent with some developer tools.

Then, you can try to create a GET request with the query string generated by the same parameters and see if it works.

Comment: Problem is that I'm not a developer for the site, I just need to be able to direct people to a specific set of search results

Comment: @user2064849 My answer is exactly what you need to do. Do some tests with that page and take note of the parameters that are sent, then try to mimic the request adding a query string to the URL you're redirecting to.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP and CURL with POST parameters.

For example:

```
$post_data = array("SessionSearch.Location"=>$location,"SessionSearch.DateFrom"=>$date_from);

$url = "https://my.blood.co.uk/SessionFinder";

$ch = curl_init(); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, $cookie_file);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 60); 

$response = @curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

The problem is that you have to save your session in a COOKIE file and resend that COOKIE file for every request.